# Pulse Audio not connecting to ALSA source

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, hp

## Problem

I have a problem with the Pulse Audio configuration of a new microphone. ALSA is handling the device perfectly, while the default PulseAudio module has no sound.

#### Test

With the following test I'd like to illustrate where I suspect the problem with the defualt configuration lies. Notice the setup details at the bottom.

1. Define the corresponding device and source names for AlSA and Pulse Audio.

```
DEV_ALSA_DEF=hw:2,1
DEV_PULS_DEF=alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.iec958-stereo
```

2. Unmute all channels of the card and the source and raise their volume.

```
amixer -c2 set Mic,0 0
amixer -c2 set Mic,0 100%
amixer -c2 set Mic,1 0
amixer -c2 set Mic,1 100%
pacmd set-source-mute   $DEV_PULS_DEF 0
pacmd set-source-volume $DEV_PULS_DEF 65536
```

3. Record the incoming sound with ALSA and Pulse Audio recommended API's.

```
arecord -f dat -r 48000 -D $DEV_ALSA_DEF -d 10 out_alsa_def.wav
timeout 10 pacat -r --channels=2 --file-format=wav --device $DEV_PULS_DEF out_puls_def.wav
```

#### Analysis

I have tested this code after a reboot, and after I started `pavucontrol`, to ensure the Pulse Audio services are running properly. The result: `out_alsa_def.wav` is an exact and clear record, while `out_puls_def.wav` is completely silent/empty/blank. My first question: **Why can't Pulse Audio connect to the channels from ALSA?**.

## Workaround

I was able to find a workaround with a new source created from the ALSA card.

#### Test

1. Create a “clone” of `$DEV_PULS_DEF` by loading a/the Pulse Audio source module corresponding to the card `$DEV_ALSA_DEF` “manually”.

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=$DEV_ALSA_DEF
DEV_PULS_MAN=alsa_input.hw_2_1
```

2. Unmute the source and raise the volume.

```
pacmd set-source-mute   $DEV_PULS_MAN 0
pacmd set-source-volume $DEV_PULS_MAN 65536
```

3. Record the incoming sound.

```
timeout 10 pacat -r --channels=2 --file-format=wav --device $DEV_PULS_MAN out_puls_man.wav
```

#### Analysis

This time, the output file `out_puls_man.wav` is a perfect record. I conclude, that the “manually” loaded source gets the channels of ALSA while the by default created source can't access it. This implies, to me, that something inside the automatic Pulse Audio configuration is failing. My second question: **Why is the manually loaded source more successful?**

#### But…

The [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-alsa-source) advices against the use of `module-alsa-source` and suggest to use `module-udev-detect` whenever possible. However, `$ pacmd load-module module-udev-detect`, is not solving the problem. Third question: **How to fix this properly with recommended tools only and what can go wrong with this workaround?**

## Setup

### Microphone

The microphone of issue is part of the build in webcam of a new HP E27d G4 connected via USB-C. The microphone is stereo and uses the Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input profile. The video transmission worked out of the box.

### System

```
$ inxi -SA
System:
  Host: rivendell Kernel: 6.1.80-1-MANJARO
    arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: i3 v: 4.23
    Distro: Manjaro Linux
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: HP USB Audio
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
    type: USB
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.80-1-MANJARO
    status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PulseAudio v: 17.0
    status: active
```

### Audio configuration

Created after the script was executed.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

  [some more output]

card 2: Audio [USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ amixer -c2
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 47
  Front Left: Capture 47 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 47 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',1
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 47
  Front Left: Capture 47 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 47 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

```
$ pacmd list-sources
5 source(s) available.

[some more output]

    index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.iec958-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9047
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4:1.0/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "03f0"
        device.vendor.name = "HP, Inc"
        device.product.id = "086d"
        device.product.name = "USB Audio"
        device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio"
        device.string = "iec958:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "384000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "192000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        device.description = "USB Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    ports:
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    active port: <iec958-stereo-input>

[some more output]

  index: 4
    name: <alsa_input.hw_2_1>
    driver: <module-alsa-source.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9040
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 25
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio #1"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "1"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4:1.0/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "03f0"
        device.vendor.name = "HP, Inc"
        device.product.id = "086d"
        device.product.name = "USB Audio"
        device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio"
        device.string = "hw:2,1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "384000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "192000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.description = "USB Audio"
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone-usb"
```

```
$ pactl list cards
 [some more output]

Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 7
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4:1.0/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "03f0"
        device.vendor.name = "HP, Inc"
        device.product.id = "086d"
        device.product.name = "USB Audio"
        device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "USB Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 32823, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 39268, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Stereo Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 39323, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 38268, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5565, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 38323, available: yes)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 300, available: yes)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 365, available: no)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 33123, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: input:iec958-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo

 [some more output]
```

## Failed approaches

1. `$ pacmd load-module module-udev-detect`
2. `$ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service` and `$ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.socket`
3. `$ pacmd load-module module-remap-source master=$DEV_PULS_DEF`
4. `$ ffmpeg -f pulse -i $DEV_PULS_DEF output.wav`
5. `$ pamac reinstall pulseaudio` and `pamac build pulseaudio`
6. `pavucontrol` (no amplitude visible)